# Boost build failed on Fedora-34

Tags: fedora, gcc, g++, boost

I am trying to install boost_1_55_0 on Fedora 34 (non-root user in a venv)

1. I download the `.tar.gz` file
2. I extract it using `tar zxvf boost_1_55_0.tar.gz`
3. I cd into `boost_1_55_0`
4. I run `./bootstrap.sh`
5. I run `./b2 -q -j2 --prefix=$PWD --libdir=$PWD/lib64 --layout=system link=static install || echo FAILURE`

The problem happens in step 5 where I get FAILURE.

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-11/release/link-static/converter/builtin_converters.o...
...failed updating 1 target...
FAILURE
```

I checked that I have the following installed:

boost-devel-1.75.0-4.fc34.x86_64 and bzip2-devel-1.0.8-6.fc34.x86_64

I also tried boost 1.75.0 and 1.64.0 and I am still getting FAILURE message

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to install boost on your own if you already have boost-devel installed? Regardless of that, there should be a better error message than just "FAILURE" somewhere.

Comment: @Wieland I am working with mosesdecoder. Whenever I compile without boost, I get the following error: Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam". That's why I am trying to manually install it.